Arcade game similar to Commando, but better music
I'm trying to find the ROMs for an arcade game I played circa 1987. It was very similar to Commando in general concept - vertical scroller, very simple isometrics, guns and grenades.
Although it was clearly a clone, the thing that I remember was that the music was very catchy with a solid baseline. Commando sounds like a couple of paired-up AY's or maybe a 2250. This was better.
Does anyone have a guess, or perhaps a pointer to a list of similar games?

What good would the ROMs do unless you had compatible hardware? That is, assuming "arcade game" means "standalone purpose-built coin-operated big machine" and not "video game console".

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact MAME?

@kouta-kun Fascinating. I think I have heard the acronym before but never looked at it until now.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact ROM dump, in short just ROM

MAME is THE solution to emulate almost anything

Could it just have been a different version of Commando? For example, Wikipedia states: "The Commodore 64 port's theme, a more complex and extended version of the arcade music, was created in less than 12 hours by Rob Hubbard" who "took one listen to the original arcade version and started working on the C64 version." (so he composed the new version from scratch.)

Similar games with a 'war' theme from the late 1980s:
Battle Field (SNK)
Guerilla War (SNK)
Guevara (SNK)
Ikari Warriors (and sequels) (SNK)
Time Soldiers (SNK)
Heavy Barrel (Data East)
Mercs (Capcom)

Is it possible that it's Who Dares Wins which got an injunction for being too similar to Commando?

This is definitely the closest lookalike to Commando, but can't hardly hear much background music, only effects.

I don't think it ever made it to being an arcade game. The music was a very jazzy version of the River Kwai March

@scruss: ah right. Maybe this was only on C64 and other home computers

Ahh, I didn't get that you mean in-game music,  not menu music.
